# no "\n" but new line being made?

Tags: python, python-3.x

There is no `\n` in my code but when I print out all my variables, it creates a newline meaning my last variable is printed on another line.

my code :

```
with open("read_it.txt", "r") as text_file:
    for items in text_file:
        line = items.split(",")
        if GTIN in items:
           product = line[1]
           indprice = line[2]
           finprice = float(indprice)* float(Quantity)
           print(GTIN,product,Quantity,"£",indprice,"£",finprice)
```

current output (wrong) :

```
086947367 banana 2 £ 0.50
 £ 1.0
```

I want :

```
86947367 banana 2 £ 0.50 £ 1.0
```

any help appreciated.

Comment: Could your terminal be wrapping the line?

Comment: The lines in a file **do** contain `\n` and python does **not** strip the final `\n` nor does `split(',')` remove anything except the separator, hence `indprice` contains a newline at the end.

Comment: Just to verify, you could `print(repr(indprice))`. You'll see the newline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call readline on a file object (which you're doing implicitly in your for loop), it leaves the trailing '\n' and/or '\r' characters.  In this case, your indprice variable still contains that trailing '\n'.

Try:

```
line = items.strip('\r\n').split(',')
```

Or, if it's a small text file that you can pull entirely into memory:

```
for items in text_file.read().split('\n'):
```